# psql: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ssl, postgresql-9.5

Trying to connect to postgresql server using command prompt.

Command used:

`psql "sslmode=require host=localhost dbname=test"`

Error thrown:

> psql: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

[image]

Please help me out on this.
Thanks.

Comment: which part of the error message is giving you trouble?

Comment: both. My problem is why this warning is coming? How to get rid of this warning? @Burki

Comment: from what you showed, you explicitly set `sslmode=require`. Since apparently your server does not support, ssl, try to leave it out?

Comment: Thanks to me..I saved myself for the same issue after 7-8 years again.. lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-ssl.html) suggests that you might try

```
psql "sslmode=disable host=localhost dbname=test"
```

or (probably better)

```
psql "sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test"
```

That way you should be able to connect to your server.

Comment: What's VERY notable is that the help given from the command line utility doesn't work at all, but your inside-qutationmarks version does! This is very much NOT like the Postgres community  - somebody should be very embarrassed!

Comment: What if I get this error during the very installation?

Comment: I got this during installation of the stack builder tools.