# How do I resolve the heroku pg:pull error - "psql: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required"?

Tags: postgresql, heroku-cli

[Per the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull), I'm trying to pull a remote heroku postgres database to a local postgres database (docker postgres container, version 9.6) using a heroku-cli command similar to the following:

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/my_local_app_database --app my_heroku_app
```

I've also attempted to add the `sslmode` parameter to the db URL, like so (`sslmode=disable`):

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/my_local_app_database?sslmode=disable --app my_heroku_app
```

And so (`sslmode=require`):

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/my_local_app_database?sslmode=require --app my_heroku_app
```

The command fails either way with the following message:

```
psql: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [psql: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350600/psql-server-does-not-support-ssl-but-ssl-was-required)

Comment: use `sslmode=disable` or `sslmode=allow`. It should work

Comment: Try heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=require

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was not specifying the target database in the URL (even though the question does).

The wrong command I was running (note the missing target database from the URL):

```
heroku pg:pull postgresql-silhouetted-12345 postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 --app my-app-name
```

I was able to pull the database with:

```
PGUSER=postgres PGHOST=127.0.0.1 heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL my_local_db --app my-app-name
```

Note that is also valid to add PGPASSWORD=xyz, PGPORT=5432, etc...

I set up Postgres with docker-compose, just like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

Comment: Thanks, but a little more detail will make your answer helpful to Postgresql noobs like myself.